# Template declaration in function declaration that already has a return type?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm following a C++/SDL2 programming tutorial series for 2D gaming. I was following along on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsvI8Sng6dk&list=PLhfAbcv9cehhkG7ZQK0nfIGJC_C-wSLrx&index=9) video and he wrote this bit of code.

```
using ComponentID = std::size_t;

inline ComponentID getComponentID()
{
    static ComponentID lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

template <typename T> inline ComponentID getComponentID() noexcept
{
    static ComponentID typeID = getComponentID();
    //typeID below is being used like a function???
    return typeID(); //<- error and won't compile, I believe this was a typo
}
```

I don't understand why `template<typename T>` is put on that line for `inline ComponentID getComponentID() noexcept`. Why is that there? Obviously, there's no semicolon after a template declaration so I suppose it can be put on the same line but why? Is there something I'm missing? I haven't finished the video yet as this perplexed me and didn't wanna just go through the whole video copying code and not understanding it. Any hints?

**EDIT:** I know how templates work, I don't need a lesson on that. But there's already a return type in the declaration of that function which is what I was asking about. Not for strangers to teach me about the C++ language.

```
template <typename T> inline ComponentID getComponentID() noexcept
```

**ComponentID** aka `std::size_t` already specifies the return type does it not? `T`'s definition is put on the same line and is not used in that function. This is what I'm asking about. Did I miss something? Because I didn't think you could have multiple return types for a function. So since it isn't the return type and it isn't used in the function itself or as a type for a parameter what is its use in this context?

Comment: Where did you get that code from?

Comment: Are you asking why there is no linebreak after `template <typename T>`?

Comment: I agree that it doesn't appear that the template is used anywhere in that function.  Perhaps the creator of the video is preparing for some neat trick later. Perhaps they are a Cargo Cult Programmer parroting something they saw years ago and do not understand. I'd have to watch the video to get a better feel.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, just making sure I'm not blind and missing something. It seemed like a typo but I wasn't sure if this was some rarely used nuance of the language.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know what a template is first of all. I know what it's used for as well. What I don't understand is its use in this case. See my edit. It's not the return type, parameter type or used in the function anywhere so it's a seemingly random and useless template delcaration in my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is to have unique incremental ID by type.

So with

```
ComponentID getComponentID()
{
    static ComponentID lastID = 0;
    return lastID++;
}

template <typename T>
ComponentID getComponentID() noexcept
{
    static ComponentID typeID = getComponentID();

    return typeID; // () was a typo indeed
}
```

We will have

```
struct Component1 {};
struct Component2 {};


getComponent<Component1>(); // Will return 0
getComponent<Component2>(); // will return 1
getComponent<Component1>(); // Will return 0
getComponent<Component2>(); // will return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates are used in order to adapt the function or a class to support more than one build in or custom type.  by doing so you can have different types used in the same code, ultimately reducing the duplicate code.

imagine that your getComponentID() had to return an int and also in another scenario need it to return a double. if  `getcomponentid()` wasn't a template function, you had to overload the function to handle both int and double return types. Since you are using templates you don't need to deal with that. the compiler will handle it for you.

one thing to note though, templates can slow down your compilation time.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Following up on your edit:

he is not returning a template type. instead of doing;

```
template<typename T>
inline ComponentID getComponentID()
{
...
...
}
```

he is putting everything in one line.as follows.

```
template <typename T> inline ComponentID getComponentID()
```

yours truly, 
some stranger from the net -.-

Comment: I understand what a template does, what I was asking was why it was declared here when the return type is already `ComponentID` aka `std::size_t` and `T` isn't used for a parameter or anything inside the function. So is this just some useless template that the video maker put in as a typo or what? As far as I can see there's no reason for the `template` declaration to be there.

Comment: you could have been clearer in your question before your edit -.-